# What's this syntax called? Is it standard C? Is it standard C++?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

```
int x = ({
    int y = 10, z;
    if (2>1) {
        z = 11;
    }
    y+z;
});
```

`x` will be 21. What is this syntax? I've seen it in C and I'm guessing it also exists in C++. Is this standard in either language?

Comment: This is neither nor: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3a5decee7792137) I checked whether I missed something exotic but I didn't.

Comment: This is a gcc extension.

Comment: I looks a little bit like a failed attempt for an initialization with an immediately called [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik interesting, can you elaborate? online g++ compiler refused.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

Comment: Even with the extension, I don't see how it would compile as `z` is out of scope where it is used.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm happy that OP asked for _standart_. :-) (So, I at least didn't write something wrong...)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik quite interesting indeed, care to add an answer?

Comment: The last statement in the inner block is evaluated, and the result is used. Mentally insert `return` at the beginning of the last statement in there, and it will become crystal clear.

Comment: Using any programming language you can write program in Fortran.

Answer (score 6):

This is a non-standard [gcc compiler extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), that lets arbitrary code get executed in an expression context and produce an expression result.

Comment: I doubt even this extension would allow to use variable out of scope.

Comment: Yes, this part is true. But, the overall syntax is what it is.

Comment: In fact, removing `-pedantic` (and fixing the issue with `z`), the complaints go away in gcc as well as g++: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aa51b02c8f942a4)